# Adding and reading a static HTML page with

Tags: files

The requirement is that the user can upload a folder, containing static HTML, CSS, JavaScript files, and a link is generated.

So, then I don't want to have any drupal styling whatsoever.

#### My initial idea

- Set a specific content type, allow multiple file upload
- Upload all the files to a specific directory via some kind of rules
- Access the page at www.example.com/sites/default/files/MYFOLDER/index.html

Do you think this is feasible approach?

Answer (score 1):

[File (Field) Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) allows you to specify path using node fields. Using it, you can have node's files in directories like `sites/default/files/custom_pages/[nid]/[node_title]/`
Just make sure to put `.htaccess` inside `custom_pages` folder, one that will allow direct html serving.

Then you can generate link using the very same tokens.

Comment: Feel like this should come with a disclaimer - that module has a _lot_ of bugs in it (currently [101](http://drupal.org/project/issues/filefield_paths?categories=bug)). We used it a while back and it caused us no end of problems that didn't manifest until the site went into production. Unhappy times, be warned :)

Comment: I never used it in anything that can be called actual production - maybe that's why it's bugs never bothered me? Oleg: Sorry for providing risky answer, I didn't know the risk. @Clive: thanks, good to know.

Comment: Hi Clive and Molot :) 

Thanks for taking time to answer me.
There are going to be additional follow-up queestions in a a while !